# Commands not executing properly with VDesk

Tags: cmd.exe, discord, bots

I have recently installed VDesk to automatically start a few Discord bots on my computer. I have a virtual desktop where I would like the bots to be. I have created a BAT file which contains the command to start a new command prompt in the second desktop, and run a command from that new terminal. My issue is that when the terminal starts, its directory is my Desktop despite the command in the BAT telling it to go to a folder within Desktop.

Bat file: `vdesk on:2 noswitch:true run:cmd /k cd C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Discord-Bot-Directory`

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks! Let me know if you need me to provide any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out. I surrounded my command in quotation marks like this: `vdesk on:2 noswitch:true run:cmd /k "cd C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Discord-Bot-Directory"`